# Element ID gets erased after being appended to a table

Tags: javascript, html

```
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  let ex = document.createElement("td");
  ex.className = "clickable";
  ex.id = "exampleid";
 / * Outputs normally here * /
  row.appendChild(ex);
  table.appendChild(row);
  console.log(table.rows[0].id);
 / * Outputs "" instead of "exampleid" * /
```

When trying to access an element from a table, the ID I assigned becomes a blank string. How can I retain the assigned ID? For context, I was using for loops to produce an array of elements.

Tried `console.log(table.rows[0].id)`, got ""

Comment: its the row that you are trying to console log but you assigned id to the column(td) not (tr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id assigned is on the `td` element not the `tr` element.

You need to access the child of tr only then the id will be available.

To access you can either use `.children` -> gives a list.

or since this is a table, you can use `.cells`

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");

var row = document.createElement("tr");
  let ex = document.createElement("td");
  ex.className = "clickable";
  ex.id = "exampleid";

  row.appendChild(ex);
  table.appendChild(row);
  console.log(table.rows[0].id); // this is the id for first row
  
console.log(table.rows[0].children[0].id); // this is the id for td element inside tr

console.log(table.rows[0].cells[0].id);
```